# calling javascript function too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

I'm just getting into Javascript and I've run into the same problem a number of times with different pieces of code: I have a function that creates a type of element and a function that does something with that type of element. It seems obvious to me that I need to call the "do something" function after the element has been created, but when I do, it ends up running more times than I'd like.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
function rightClick(){
    $(".element").mousedown(function(e){
        switch (e.which){case 3: alert( $(this).attr("id") )};
    });
};

function doubleClick(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).dblclick(function(e){
        counter++;
        elementId = "element" + counter;
        $("#new_elements").append("<div class='element'"          +
                                   "id='"    + elementId + "'"   +
                                   "style='position:absolute;"   +
                                   "top:"    + e.pageY + ";"     +
                                   "left:"   + e.pageX + ";'>"   +
                                    elementId+ "</div>");
    rightClick();
});
```

In this example, if I create 4 elements and I right-click on the first one I created, I end up getting 4 alert boxes instead of one. If I right-click on the second element I created, I get three alerts; the third: 2 alerts; the fourth: one alert.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening, and how to fix it so that I only get one alert each time I right-click on an element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Binding is the act of associating an event with a DOM element. The `.mousedown` and similar events only bind on elements that already exist.
2. Each time you call `rightClick()` you bind a new event to all current `.element` elements.
3. You can bind functions to the same element as much as you'd like, which is why you see the function being called many times.
4. For dynamic elements should checkout `.on` or `.delegate` which work like this:

Example of [jQuery.fn.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $(document.body).on("mousedown", ".element", function(e) {
   if (e.which === 3) alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Example of [jQuery.fn.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
 $(document.body).delegate(".element", "mousedown", function(e) {
   if (e.which === 3) alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Only call this once and you should be pretty much okay. If you're not using jQuery 1.7 or higher you will want to use `.delegate()` instead of `.on`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response; what you've written makes a lot of sense and I'm about to check out the documentation on .on() and .delegate(). However, it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to bind the event everytime you insert and element into the DOM. You can use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers for elements that are dynamically inserted.

```
$(document).on('mousedown','.element', (function(e){
    switch (e.which){
            case 3: alert( $(this).attr("id") ); 
            break; 
    };
});

var counter = 0;
$(document).dblclick(function(e){
    counter++;
    elementId = "element" + counter;
    $("#new_elements").append("<div class='element'"          +
                               "id='"    + elementId + "'"   +
                               "style='position:absolute;"   +
                               "top:"    + e.pageY + ";"     +
                               "left:"   + e.pageX + ";'>"   +
                                elementId+ "</div>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are adding the same handler several times, meaning that when you click a button you are re-binding the action to the same function.

Answer (score 0):

You've bound your event handler to the class '.element'. This means that every element with the class '.element' on your page will fire that event when the right click occurs.